# Extending ASP.NET MVC 4 MvcHandler

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm trying to add some functionality to the default MvcHandler. What's happening is: I wanted to have dashed url's instead of Pascal Case url's. In other words if my controller is SomeController I wanted the URL to be /some-controller instead of /SomeController.

My best workaround was: I've created one mapping file URLMappings.xml which maps each controller to each desired URL. Then I've extended the default Route class to generate outgoing url's based on this and the default RouteHandler to understand the url's based on this. Well, this works fine because even if some mapping wasn't created then the framework will use the default behavior.

My point is: with this the routing system was understanding both kinds of Url's and this leads to duplicate content SEO problem. I wanted then to implement the following:

1. Get the controller value
2. See if on some mapping the controller name matches the value
3. If it matches, then there's some preferable URL than the one that was typed, should return 404.

I've searched on the web and the only way I've found to do this was to create a new IHttpHandler. However I don't want one from scratch, since I need all MVC functionality. I just want to put this logic on the ProcessRequest, however my overidden version of the method is not being executed.

Can someone give me some idea on how to deal with this ? Sorry if the question is silly or if it's not well detailed. If there's need for more information, just tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a custom `MvcHandler` but a custom `Route`. There's a already NuGet package for this functionality called [`LowercaseRoutesMVC`](http://nuget.org/packages/LowercaseRoutesMVC). Feel free to download it, explore the [`source code`](http://lowercaseroutesmvc.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/6b7b90c5784b#LowercaseRoute.cs) and adapt if necessary (to put the dash wherever you want to put it).